# Telegram system tray icon appears black in Kubuntu 20.04

Tags: kubuntu, icons, 20.04, system-tray

As the title says telegram system tray icon is hardly visible. All appearance settings are on default.

[image]

But when I change Colors from Breeze to Breeze Dark it gets fixed.

[image]

The problem is that I like Breeze colors and I do not want to change it. Additionally, I noticed the problem is with `/usr/share/color-schemes/Breeze.colors` because when I change `ForegroundNormal=35,38,39` from `[Colors:Window]` tag to `ForegroundNormal=239,240,241` that is the value used in `BreezeDark.colors` the icon is changed to white but I get other color problems. Now looking for a solution.

Also I tried replacing all Telegram icons in `/usr/share/icons/breeze/status/22` and `/usr/share/icons/breeze/status/24` by `/usr/share/icons/breeze-dark/status/22` and `/usr/share/icons/breeze-dark/status/24` and nothing changed.

Comment: How did you install Telegram? That possibly could be relevant.

Comment: `sudo apt install telegram-desktop`

Comment: In *System Settings > Global Theme* the **Breeze** option shows the panel with a near white background and items in the system tray, including the Telegram icon are black or outlined in black. The opposite holds for the **Breeze Dark** option. The problem seems to be with the **Kubuntu** option. There, the panel background is dark, and all system tray components are white **except** the Telegram icon which is dark. I suggest you avoid the Kubuntu Global theme.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've found easy solution.
Icon that displays in tray has extension `.svg`, so it is easy to fix icons, as you want.

1. Open any file manager (I use double commander)
2. Perform search files by regular expression with string `telegram.*svg`
   You shouls receive near 15 results:

Group of `telegram-attention-panel.svg` - 4 items,

Group of `telegram-mute-panel.svg` - 4 items,

Group of `telegram-panel.svg` - 4 items

and single file `telegram.svg`

File `telegram.svg` contains classic icon with blue background and white airplane, so I use it for fix. Open `telegram.svg` in any text redactor, copy whole content and paste it in all files `telegram-panel.svg` (instead of original content of these files).

After this manipulations you will have nice icon in tray in every global theme.

Answer (score 1):

If you use non-Qt DE, such as GNOME or Windo maanger. Install `qt5ct`

Then run `qt5ct` to change Qt application settings. If the application still doesn't pick its setting, try to put `export QT_QPA_PLATFORMTHEME="qt5ct"` in your shell profile.

credit: [Manjaro wiki](https://wiki.manjaro.org/index.php?title=Set_all_Qt_app%27s_to_use_GTK%2B_font_%26_theme_settings)

Answer (score 1):

I choose replace icons in breeze theme with those have same name in breeze theme.
You can find icons in the path like */usr/share/icons/breeze/status/22*.